# How to ensure that all arguments are provided in Apache Commons CLI?

Tags: java, apache-commons, error-checking, apache-commons-cli

I don't see a standard way of checking if all Options are provided in a String[] input to 
apache's CLI library .  That is - my options are all REUIRED at the command line, otherwise, i want an exception to throw.

Im trying the following as a workaround, but getting a Nullpointer exception in the if statement...

```
PosixParser p = new PosixParser();
        CommandLine cli=p.parse(options,args);
        for(Object o : options.getOptions())
        {
            Option op = (Option)o;
            if(cli.getOptionValue(op.getName()))
            throw new ParseException("Missing argument ! " + op.getArgName() + ":"+op.getDescription());
    }
```

**UPDATE ON THIS : the getOpt() method seems to provide the arguments short name.**

However, if I replace op.getName() with opt.getLongName()... it works !

In any case.. I have 2 questions :

1) Why would an option have a null name, yet a non-null longName ?
2) Is there a way to simply ensure that all options are provided the String[] ? For example, I would like to call :

```
  if(! options.isAllProvided())
     throw new ParseException("You are missing some options ! " + StringUtils.join(userInputArray,','));
```

Comment: Just noticed  :   In order to get an option by its short name, you call getOpt() , rather than getArgName() or any other method.

Answer (score 10):

Here's how you can set an Option to be required:

```
Option logfile = OptionBuilder.withArgName( "file" )
            .isRequired() // make it required
            .hasArg()
            .withDescription(  "use given file for log" )
            .create( "logfile" );
```

(I don't think there's an easy way to make all Options required in one step)

Comment: hmmm... thats to bad.  looks like this api needs resurrection.

Comment: You have indeed to mark the options as required. If some options are missing you'll then get an exception containing the list of the missing options.

Comment: Indeed it is verbose and ugly, but I find that making a Factory class with methods like `makeRequiredOption` can greatly improve the readability of your main class.

Comment: `OptionBuilder` is deprecated now. Use `Option.builder("file")` instead